# Android: Get all PendingIntents set with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm setting an alarm like this:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingEvent);
```

I'm interested in removing all the alarms that where previously set, clearing them.

Is there a way for me to do that or to get all the alarms that are currently set so that I can delete them manually ?

Comment: This guys shows how to list current alarms:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522792/get-list-of-active-pendingintents-in-alarmmanager

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to create your pending intent and then cancel it

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyPendingIntentService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, updateServiceIntent, 0);

    // Cancel alarms
    try {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Correct. It is not possible to query the AlarmManager for existing PendingIntents. You have to keep a reference on them.

Comment: No reference needed. alarmManager.cancel cancels all of them docs:
Remove any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)), will be canceled.

Comment: How do keep the reference to them I store everything in database So how do i keep reference to it ?

Comment: What if my intent has some extra value or bundle ... do i need to create the same intent with the same extra value to be able to cancel the intent?

Comment: also need to perform pendingUpdateIntent.cancelt() to make it work completely

Comment: @FinalDark extras are not considered when matching `Intent`s, so it makes no difference what extras were in the `Intent` when you created it. You can cancel the alarm by using an `Intent` without extras.

Comment: What if I lost the references to the pending intents? They are going to be enabled forever until user restarts her device?

Comment: @JesusAlmaral you would build the pending intent using the same Id, note you don't create pending intents, you "get" them. You only need to keep references to the ID, let Android handle the pending intent bit.

Answer (score 87):

You don't have to keep reference to it. Just define a new PendingIntent like exactly the one that you defined in creating it.

For example:

if I created a PendingIntent to be fired off by the AlarmManager like this:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + alarm.ID));
alarmIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(alarm.ID));
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmDateTime, displayIntent);
```

Then somewhere in your other code (even another activity) you can do this to cancel:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + alarm.ID));
alarmIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(alarm.ID));
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);

alarmManager.cancel(displayIntent);
```

The important thing here is to set the PendingIntent with exactly the same data and action, and other criteria as well as stated here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29

Comment: +1 for alarmIntent.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + alarm.ID));
alarmIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(alarm.ID));

Comment: @gilsaints88 : can you explain me, what is the function of alarm.ID and how can I declare that in both of my activity ?

Comment: @mas_bejo the alarm.ID on setData(...) is for uniqueness of alarm so that we can clear any previously set alarm with same alarm.ID while the setAction(...) was used so that the intent passed from a notification is the right value when returned to an Activity via onNewIntent().

I use setData and setAction when setting up my alarm and when I'm receiving it from my Activity coming from notification I get the intent by overriding onNewIntent of Activity. the intent I get is the correct one because of setAction(...) earlier. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, By setData and SetAction notification get cancelled in my OPPO phone but its not get cancelled in my MOTO phone. Can you please suggest.

Comment: @NiravPatel may I ask what Android version is your OPPO and what Android version is your MOTO? Thanks

Comment: @gilsaints88 : OPPO having 5.1.1 & MOTO having 6.0

Comment: If you wanna create multiple Alarms you should have multiple pending Intents with different ids. So you should save the ids and for next cancellations.

Answer (score 26):

To cancel an alarm you need to re-create the same PendingIntent and pass the same request code.

So, I have created an AlarmUtils to help me saving all the request codes in the preferences to cancel it in the future if it is needing. All you need is to use the following class and call the following methods:

- `addAlarm` to add a new alarm and pass a request code.
- `cancelAlarm` to remove an alarm, you need to re-create the same
  Intent and pass the same request code.
- `hasAlarm` to verify if that alarm as added, you need to re-create 
  the same Intent and pass the same request code.
- `cancelAllAlarms` to remove ALL alarms setted.

My AlarmUtils

```
public class AlarmUtils {

    private static final String sTagAlarms = ":alarms";

    public static void addAlarm(Context context, Intent intent, int notificationId, Calendar calendar) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

        saveAlarmId(context, notificationId);
    }

    public static void cancelAlarm(Context context, Intent intent, int notificationId) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();

        removeAlarmId(context, notificationId);
    }

    public static void cancelAllAlarms(Context context, Intent intent) {
        for (int idAlarm : getAlarmIds(context)) {
            cancelAlarm(context, intent, idAlarm);
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasAlarm(Context context, Intent intent, int notificationId) {
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
    }

    private static void saveAlarmId(Context context, int id) {
        List<Integer> idsAlarms = getAlarmIds(context);

        if (idsAlarms.contains(id)) {
            return;
        }

        idsAlarms.add(id);

        saveIdsInPreferences(context, idsAlarms);
    }

    private static void removeAlarmId(Context context, int id) {
        List<Integer> idsAlarms = getAlarmIds(context);

        for (int i = 0; i < idsAlarms.size(); i++) {
            if (idsAlarms.get(i) == id)
                idsAlarms.remove(i);
        }

        saveIdsInPreferences(context, idsAlarms);
    }

    private static List<Integer> getAlarmIds(Context context) {
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(prefs.getString(context.getPackageName() + sTagAlarms, "[]"));

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
                ids.add(jsonArray2.getInt(i));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ids;
    }

    private static void saveIdsInPreferences(Context context, List<Integer> lstIds) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (Integer idAlarm : lstIds) {
            jsonArray.put(idAlarm);
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(context.getPackageName() + sTagAlarms, jsonArray.toString());

        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: probably worth making `removeAlarmId` public so folks can remove ids when the notification has arrived.

Comment: You can use `cancelAlarm()` for that instead because you need to create the pendingIntent to cancel the alarm

Comment: ah interesting, so even if an alarm has passed it is still enqueued?

Comment: `PreferenceManager` is deprecated now

Comment: @VadimKotov you're probably using androidx already so you need to add implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0' to your build gradle dependencies to use the androidx PrefenerceManager which is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If save the PendingIntent id in SharedPreference or db, you will get wrong value when **Android reboot** or **your package force-stop**

You can save all your previous PendingIntent to another new PendingIntent, then cancel all later

for example

```
    void createSomeAlarmAndSave() {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class).setAction(ACTION_XXX), 0);
        getSystemService(AlarmManager.class).setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1000 * 60 * 15, 1000 * 60 * 15, pendingIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class).setAction(ACTION_XXX), 0);
        getSystemService(AlarmManager.class).setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1000 * 60 * 20, 1000 * 60 * 20, pendingIntent1);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class).setAction(ACTION_XXX), 0);
        getSystemService(AlarmManager.class).setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1000 * 60 * 25, 1000 * 60 * 25, pendingIntent2);

        //save all previous PendingIntent to another new PendingIntent
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class).putExtra("previous", new PendingIntent[]{pendingIntent, pendingIntent1, pendingIntent2}), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

cancel all previous PendingIntent

```
    void cancelAllPreviousAlarm() {
        //acquire the dedicated PendingIntent
        PendingIntent pendingIntentAllPrevious = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        if (pendingIntentAllPrevious != null) {
            try {
                pendingIntentAllPrevious.send(this, 0, null, new PendingIntent.OnFinished() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSendFinished(PendingIntent pendingIntent, Intent intent, int resultCode, String resultData, Bundle resultExtras) {
                        for (Parcelable parcelable : intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("previous")) {
                            //alarm will cancel when the corresponding PendingIntent cancel
                            ((PendingIntent) parcelable).cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }, null);
                pendingIntentAllPrevious.cancel();
            } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you re-creating the PendingIntent:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, 0, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```