# Listing all PendingIntents from AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Get all PendingIntents set with AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315611/android-get-all-pendingintents-set-with-alarmmanager)

I am looking to list all pending alarms set in my app, so later i can add a cancel button for each individual alarm.

The problem is, I'm not sure how this would be done at all, and have no idea where to start.

I would be grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Record all `PendingIntents` that you register with `AlarmManager`.

Step #2: Use the results from Step #1 for your cancel buttons.

There is no way to query `AlarmManager` for scheduled alarms -- you have to track those yourself.

Comment: 'adb shell dumpsys' -- look for "Current Alarm Manager state:"

Comment: I do not understand why it is not possible to query AlarmManager to get alarms. It is so bad that I cannot find my alarms there and I always have to keep a reference of my alarms.