# Can I get all current intents setted by AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm

Can I get all current intents setted by AlarmManager, I wanna know how many intents are setted and what are they?

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 300000, foo);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522792/get-list-of-active-pendingintents-in-alarmmanager) thread. Unfortunately, it seems that this is only possible using dumpsys.