# Why my AlarmManager doesn't trigger BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarmmanager

In my application I'm trying to call `BroadcastReceiver` using `AlarmManager` to call the service every minute. But for some reason it's not getting called. I can't figure out the reason for this. I'm writing this code by following a working project, and I couldn't find anything different. Please help.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shan.chathuranga.smsscheduler">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ServiceChecker"/>

        <service
            android:name="services.MessageSendingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <receiver android:name="broadcastReceiver.MessageServiceScheduler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="broadcastReceiver.MessageServiceTrigger"/>

        <receiver
            android:name="broadcastReceiver.SendBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SMS_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="broadcastReceiver.DeliveryBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SMS_DELIVERED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mainUI;
    private TextView dateTime;
    private Button serviceChecker;
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        this.initializeDatabase();
        this.triggerService();

        mainUI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_ui);
        dateTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_time);
        serviceChecker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.service);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateTime.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

        mainUI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        serviceChecker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ServiceChecker.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    public void initializeDatabase() {
        DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.open();
        dbAdapter.close();
    }

    public void triggerService() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageServiceTrigger.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

    }
}
```

MessageServiceTrigger.java

```
public class MessageServiceTrigger extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = MessageServiceTrigger.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,TAG+" onReceive get called");
    }
}
```

Comment: the documentation for setInexactRepeating() :

As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. Because this method has been available since API 3, your application can safely call it and be assured that it will get similar behavior on both current and older 
versions of Android.
check this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change your `REPEAT_TIME = 1000;` This corresponds to 1 second, not one minute.

```
private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 60000;
```

Next try to change your `triggerService()` method as below.

```
public void triggerService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageServiceTrigger.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
}
```

Comment: What do your get? App crashes? Or it works fine but only alarms are not getting called? If you receive errors, please include them into your question

Comment: That's the problem I'm not getting any errors. That Log message inside MessageServiceTrigger onReceive not get's display.

Comment: Could you include Log message inside of `triggerService()` method to know if app is running code in it?

Comment: No No, Trigger service method executes without problem. From that method MessageServiceTrigger class extending BroadcastReceiver not gets executed. That Log message inside onReceive method should printed in logcat. But it didn't show up. I even put break points and debug to make sure.

Comment: Check this link to see, if your alarm is indeed setup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742884/how-to-read-adb-shell-dumpsys-alarm-output.  Also, for debugging purpose, increase the interval to 2 min or so and see if at least the trigger happens.

Comment: @ChathurangaShanJayarathna I have updated my answer please have a look at it. Try to repeat it exactly as it is

Comment: I think what ever the mistake I made in my 'MessageServiceTrigger' class
Because I call it manually like this. 'Intent intent = new Intent("com.shan.chathuranga.smsscheduler.broadcastReceiver.MessageServiceTrigger");
        sendBroadcast(intent);'

This should show the log message inside 'onReceive' Right ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    <receiver android:name="broadcastReceiver.MessageServiceTrigger" 
              android:process=":remote" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there any rule that saying you shouldn't use capital letters for package names. Because that's what wasted my all day. Since I have another four broadcast receivers in my project I created a package with the name of `broadcastReceiver`. that's where I placed my `MessageServiceTrigger` class. I change that in to `broadcast_receiver` just because I don't have any other thing to change in my code and I have working project with me which have Identical code that working fine. Now it's working. Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Does your alarms work now? You have only changed the package name?

Comment: The change I mentions above.

Comment: Actually there is no such rule. I have a project with a package to hold all receivers like you have. And I use capital letters and everything works fine. Strange that this solved your problem