# Setting the Notification on next day if the time has passed

Tags: android, notifications, calendar, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I'm setting multiple alarms on repeat (everyday) on a button click. they are working fine if all of the time is greater then the time of button press.But if any time in the array has passed, it is generating the notification right after the button click and as many as passed.
I have tried to put a condition to check if time has passed so set the alarm on the next day but it is not working I keep getting notification on the button click.

here is my mainActivity code for button click

```
 int[] h = new int[C.getCount()];
    int[] m = new int[C.getCount()];
    long[] AllTime = new long[C.getCount()];


    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    alertIntent.putExtra("strings", DealTimes);  // sending deal times thoruh string to AlertReceverrr !!!

    for (int i = 0; i < C.getCount(); i++) {


        h[i] = Integer.valueOf(DealTimes[i].split(":")[0]);
        m[i] = Integer.valueOf(DealTimes[i].split(":")[1]);
        //   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Time at 16th index " + h + "min " + m, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h[i]);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m[i]);
        calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        AllTime[i] = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

       // checking if current time is greater the any of the time in array
         if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        if ( curHr > h[i])
        {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }    

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Setting Alarm" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AllTime[i],
      //          PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,AllTime[i],AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        // recinving noti within 30 seconds of button press, and generting as much noti as are passed. DUH. was reciving right on time witout delay before setting on repeat
```

and here Is my alertReciver code

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
    Log.i("okk", "cathing intent values through break" + Arrays.toString(myStrings));


    createNotification(context,"Time is here baby","5 sec hogae hen beta","Alert");
    Log.i("okk", "cathing intent values through break" + Arrays.toString(myStrings));


}

public void createNotification(Context context,String msg,String msgText, String msgAlert)
{
    final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();  // unique request code

                                                                          PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,_id, new Intent(context,MainActivity.class),0);  // changed from 0 to _id

    NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_play)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setContentText(msgText);

    // now intent we want to fire when noti is clicked

    mbuilder.setContentIntent(notificationIntent);

    // how person is notified

    mbuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    mbuilder.setAutoCancel(true); 
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService((Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));

//    Log.i("okk", "NOTIFIED " + intent.getExtras());

    notificationManager.notify(1,mbuilder.build());  // changes from 1 to _id
           }
```

Comment: Your comparison is a little off. You're comparing an hour to a time in milliseconds. Check how it's done on the linked duplicate. And you'll want to do that comparison before you assign the value to `AllTime[i]`.

Comment: @MikeM. It's not working for me I tried !!

Comment: Update your post with your current code.

Comment: @MikeM. just updated, check. and I'm using both comparisons now editing my first one, still not working.

Comment: Remove the `if ( curHr > h[i]) {...}` block, and move `AllTime[i] = calendar.getTimeInMillis();` to after `if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {...}`.

Comment: @MikeM. Stupid me !!! thanks a lot , it worked :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134239/discussion-between-shahtaj-khalid-and-mike-m).

Comment: @MikeM. hey I got a little problem here wondering if you can help with that too, now according my code these notifications should be repeated on the next day but none of it are repeating.

Comment: Is your device rebooting? Alarms don't persist through a reboot. You have to set them again at boot. Also, since API 19, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 19+, `setRepeating()` is not exact, so the alarm might not fire until a while after the set time.

Comment: @MikeM. No I didn't rebooted the device. and yes my target is 23 but as setRepeating() is not exact, still it should repeat after some time? but it is not repeating any of them at all.

Comment: Are you forcibly stopping your app? If an app is force closed, it's put back into the _stopped_ state, and the manifest Receivers won't work again until the app is run next. Or maybe your device has some sort of aggressive power management process that might be interfering. You might check through the device Settings, or any management or administrative-type app. Beyond that, all I could suggest is to test with shorter intervals; make sure that works, at least. Also, you can use adb to check the status of your alarms after a while; e.g., the next day: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28742884.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks , I will try using adb shell to check if it even sets the alarm or not. and no i'm not forcibly stopping the app. one more thing can you mention how and where to actually use this command as in the link it is asking about the output of the command, and so sorry if i'm annoying you :p

Comment: It's a command line tool. There's a pretty extensive write-up about it here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html.

Comment: @MikeM. I tried, and hey I have received a notification today out of nowehere, I think it is one of the repeating ones as I keep changing the time to test.. have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942221/how-to-read-adb-dumpsys-alarm-output