# How to read "adb shell dumpsys alarm" output - Android 13

Tags: android, adb, alarmmanager, android-alarms

The accepted answer to [How to read "adb shell dumpsys alarm" output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742884/how-to-read-adb-shell-dumpsys-alarm-output/31600886) is a masterpiece.
However, later Android versions added fields that I do not understand.

Here is an example of an Android 13 output:

> RTC_WAKEUP #28: Alarm{2311a92 type 0 origWhen 1709196900000
> whenElapsed 101358972 com.google.android.deskclock}
> tag=*walarm*:com.android.deskclock.action.UPDATE_ALARM_INSTANCES
> type=RTC_WAKEUP origWhen=2024-02-29 10:55:00.000 window=0 exactAllowReason=policy_permission repeatInterval=0 count=0 flags=0x3
> policyWhenElapsed: requester=+1h15m59s870ms app_standby=-23s210ms device_idle=-- battery_saver=-- tare=-23s210ms
> whenElapsed=+1h15m59s870ms maxWhenElapsed=+1h15m59s870ms
> Alarm clock:
> triggerTime=2024-02-29 10:55:00.000
> showIntent=PendingIntent{3ecfc63: PendingIntentRecord{85fd060 com.google.android.deskclock startActivity}}
> operation=PendingIntent{41b3b6b: PendingIntentRecord{b7516c8 com.google.android.deskclock broadcastIntent}}
> idle-options=Bundle[{android.pendingIntent.backgroundActivityAllowed=false,
> android:broadcast.temporaryAppAllowlistReasonCode=301,
> android:broadcast.temporaryAppAllowlistDuration=10000,
> android:broadcast.temporaryAppAllowlistReason=,
> android:broadcast.temporaryAppAllowlistType=0}]

There is are a few new entries: **flags**, **device_idle**, **battery_saver**
Also in some entries there is an additional section **Alarm Clock**. I wonder what is its significance.

Answer (score 0):

these means all POLICIES type,
code follow

```
static String policyIndexToString(int index) {
    switch (index) {
        case REQUESTER_POLICY_INDEX:
            return "requester";
        case APP_STANDBY_POLICY_INDEX:
            return "app_standby";
        case DEVICE_IDLE_POLICY_INDEX:
            return "device_idle";
        case BATTERY_SAVER_POLICY_INDEX:
            return "battery_saver";
        case TARE_POLICY_INDEX:
            return "tare";
        default:
            return "--unknown(" + index + ")--";
    }
}
```

battery_saver=-- means Elapsed time is 0

Comment: The code section in your answer is referring to which parameters? Please explicitly name them. Can you please annotate it and add the values of the constants?