Android AlarmManager fails to deliver alarm created with setExact if application is not running
As per Google documentation. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html "the Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running." That is exactly my use case. I create Alarm with PendingIntent in my app setting few mins in the future, then I close the application. OS needs to deliver Intent via Broadcast and wake up my app. Application then triggers some internal function once Intent delivered to the app. All works fine when I test alarm creation and receiver while application is running. Intent delivered via broadcast with high accuracy. However in case I close application after Alarm creation - nothing happens.
Relevant code:
    //Alarm creation
    val alarmManager =
                myApp.applicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            if (alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
                
                try {
                    val alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        myApp.applicationContext(),
                        id,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                    )
                    alarmManager.setExact(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        triggerAtMillis, // few mins in the future
                        alarmIntent
                    )
                } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                    // Print error
                }
    
    // handling Intent:
    class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    
        var context: Context = myApp.applicationContext()
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    // do stuff here 
    }

Application has
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Im running Android 12 , device is a TV box which powered all the time (no buttery) , holds WakeLock.
Any ideas why Android is not launching my application and delivering PendingIntent. I feel Im doing something wrong but cant figure out what...
Thanks
David

You should not need to hold a wake lock for an alarm. It is possible the manufacturer of the device cancels alarms when the app is not running, it wouldnt be the first time I have seen that

Im testing using Android emulator : Properties
avd.ini.displayname              Pixel 7 API 31
avd.ini.encoding                 UTF-8
AvdId                            Pixel_7_API_31
disk.dataPartition.size          64G
image.sysdir.1                   system-images/android-31/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
tag.display                      Google APIs
tag.id                           google_apis
vm.heapSize                      256

oh then yeah that should work, I dont see any issue with that you have posted except you dont need both USE_EXACT_ALARM and SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM, they have different intended usages

removed USE_EXACT_ALARM from manifest. Tested -> same result , if app is not running nothing happens....

I was merely just stating you had permissions you didnt need, not that it was going to fix anything. If it were to be published on the play store it would likely get rejected

right, thanks. I pretty much in dead end in this situation. Spent hours experimenting, googling etc etc.

For additional debugging you could try looking at all the active alarms to see if your alarm is still scheduled with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742884/how-to-read-adb-shell-dumpsys-alarm-output/31600886#31600886

try adding Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND to the intent you passed to the pending intent and use .setAlarmClock() instead of setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() because
it is more accurate here is a more explained answer:link

Thanks, tried that approach unfortunately not working. My issue is not a clock precision but situation that  application is not launched by AlarmManager. Perhaps I misunderstood AlarmManager capabilities?
