# question on making sure user gets notification that he schedules on android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been exploring launching an app with no servers(just an app on android phone), but when a user reboots his phone, he loses the reminder notifications that were set previously in my app which is not opened that often as it is more a reminder app.  I have this previous post that I just added a bounty too

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293900/code-in-trying-to-reschedule-previous-alarm-notifications-in-android-after-a-reb
```

BUT I am starting to wonder and **have a second question**.  SHOULD I instead change my architecture such that I have to have a server portion and fire notifications through Google FCM api instead to send notifications to my app every day to potentially reschedule alarms that are dead since the phone rebooted.  Is there even a way to see if my notifications are still scheduled and will go off at the correct times?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

I put a very detailed answer on your mentioned question, but I will also chime in here.

> SHOULD I instead change my architecture such that I have to have a server portion and fire notifications through Google FCM api instead to send notifications to my app every day to potentially reschedule alarms that are dead since the phone rebooted.

Short answer, no.

Long answer, if you are using FCM to trigger a daily check to ensure that all notifications are scheduled, then why not just use it to trigger the reminder notifications themselves? FCM has high-priority messages that will wake the phone and allow your application to execute some code. However, if you are planning on releasing this application to the public, this ends up creating a privacy issue that isn't present if the application keeps all information local. If you are the only user, then it makes even less sense to use a server to handle anything. If it is for a couple of friends, then a server MIGHT be an option, but I would still recommend against it even if they are fine without a privacy policy and the such because it is an unnecessary additional cost to the application.

> Is there even a way to see if my notifications are still scheduled and will go off at the correct times?

If my answer above didn't already take care of this, while it might be technically possible to discover whether or not your application has any pending Alarms set with AlarmManager, it is not feasible to do so. AlarmManager does not provide any sort of visibility to any set alarms (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949522/android-get-list-of-active-alarms)). You would have to figure out some way to keep track of this yourself, but like I mentioned in the first part, if you are going to us FCM to trigger a job to schedule the notifications you may as well use FCM to trigger the notifications.