# scheduling service using AlarmManager in android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, scheduling

I'm trying to schedule a service through `AlarmManager` with following code:

The `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` is as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   /*
    if(isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service already Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
    */
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int hour = 12;
    int minutes = 14;
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent (getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
   // Intent i = new Intent();
   // i.setClass(getBaseContext(),MyService.class);
   // alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), 0, i, 0);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, i, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

while the `AlarmReceiver` is as follows:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

I've also tried `PendingIntent.getService()`, as is visible in code.

the service was starting as required without scheduling...please suggest.

or, is it that, since `setInexactRepeating` is not exact ...in that case how long will i have to wait.

Comment: any shorter way to check if alarmManager has been set..i'm sure you can makeout i'm a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

instead of

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: checking, no response yet.....can you suggest any way, other than waiting for service to start, to check if alarm has been set

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522792/get-list-of-active-pendingintents-in-alarmmanager

Comment: on repetitive adb shell dumpsys alarm, i could see value of WHEN change from 9m to 4 sec to presently 23h59m, but the service hasn't started..

Comment: why are you using getBaseContext()? Try to use your activity as context.

Comment: my mistake, i did not define the receiver in manifest, now ...able to start both the service and the broadcast receiver. Thanx @Roman Zhukov

Comment: you should add randomness so request from different devices won't hit the server simultaneously - if you use it with a server