# Android cancel all alarmmanager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've question with cancel() in AlarmManager

when I set alarm I use AlarmManger, this my code

```
        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder()
        .append(time).append(".")
        .append(day);
        String action = q.toString();

        Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(Edit_Contract.this, ReceiverContract.class);
        AlarmIntent.setAction(action);
        AlarmManager AlmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Edit_Contract.this, 0, AlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and then,I want to cancel all alarm which I set,what should I do

Comment: Have you looked at AlarmManager.cancel(yourPendingIntent)? Thats the only thing I can see looking at the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you sure you did the research on the nose? Here's what i found during 2 minutes of looking: [Android: Get all PendingIntents set with AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315611/android-get-all-pendingintents-set-with-alarmmanager)

Comment: sorry,for my question was not clear,This research can cancel alarm one by one,but my question want to cancel all of alam which set not one by one

Comment: @Moyshe: this almost makes me cry... Why does Android allways lacks simple cancelAll function (also for Nearby Devices) This ruïns my planning all the time.