# Cancel all the alarms set using alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, system-services

I want to cancel all the alarms that are set. I have searched a lot and tried a lot of things but nothing worked. When I set an alarm for say after 2 minutes and then I cancel it, it will still fire after 2 minutes.

The method used to create the alarms:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(c, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("task", task);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

This is to cancel alarms:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(c, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did replacing `PendingIntent.getActivity` with `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` and `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` with 0 work?

Comment: using getBroadcast, none of the alarms fire (bcoz my alarm calls an activity, not a broadcast)..... Using FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT doesnt work... I have tried it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android AlarmManager: is there a way to cancell ALL the alarms set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569896/android-alarmmanager-is-there-a-way-to-cancell-all-the-alarms-set)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you schedule your alarms, your second parameter to `getActivity()` is `code` and when you try to cancel your alarms, your second parameter to `getActivity()` is `0`. This will only successfully cancel an alarm whose `code` was `0`.

If you want to *consistently* cancel the alarms, you need to create equivalent `PendingIntents`, which means the same Intent object (with the same action, component, data, flags and other attributes) and the same code. It's worth mentioning that the `Context` you used to create the `Intent` does not need to be the same for cancellation to see it as the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I got the concept. But I have to set multiple alarms, so having same second parameter to getActivity() will replace the old alarm instead of creating a new one. How shall I overcome this?

Comment: to set multiple alarms, just use multiple values for the variable code inside a loop.

Comment: @HirakChhatbar: "How shall I overcome this?" -- keep track of the codes that you are using, then use those same codes when creating the `PendingIntent` to replace or cancel the alarm.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I ended up creating a separate activity for cancelling the alarms where I would pass the code for the alarm that I want to delete and then delete it with that code..... Thank you for the help

Comment: The extras that I pass to my intent that I send to the pendingIntent change when I recreate the pendingIntent. Is this the reason why my alarms wouldn't cancel?

Comment: @Sagar: I cannot answer that. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing what you are doing and what your specific symptoms are.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the alarm with request code (second parameter for `getActivity`) equals to `code`, while when you are cancelling the alarm, the second parameter is `0`. If the value of `code` is not `0` the alarm wouldn't be cancelled.

In order to fire and cancel multiple alarms, you need to use unique value for `requestCode` (second parameter) in `PendingIntent.getActivity`

See this code that will set 3 Alarms using three unique request Codes,

```java
for (int requestCode = 1; requestCode <= 3; requestCode++) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, requestCode, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

You can cancel the Alarm using the same `requestCode` (and other parameters) that were used to set it.

The other parameters which are needed to matched are:

- The "action" in the `Intent` must be the same (or both null). Otherwise they do not match.
- The "data" in the `Intent` must be the same (or both null). Otherwise they do not match.
- The "type" (of the data) in the `Intent` must be the same (or both null). Otherwise they do not match.
- The "package" and/or "component" in the `Intent` must be the same (or both null). Otherwise they do not match. "package" and "component" fields are set for "explicit" `Intent`s.
- The list of "categories" in the `Intent` must be the same. Otherwise they do not match.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205696/3590155) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To cancel an alarm you need no re-create the same PendingIntent and pass the same request code.

You can see my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315611/android-get-all-pendingintents-set-with-alarmmanager/42239371#42239371)

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel alarm its intent must be same with intent which used for set alarm .

so just add following 2 line

intent.putExtra("task", task);

intent.putExtra("id", id);

So your final code will be

```
Intent intent = new Intent(c, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("task", task);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```