# Unable to cancel alarm and start with new data(alarm manager)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a class notifer that is running in the background. It restarts itself after every 1 min. onReceive of notifer is:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context contextn, final Intent intent)
{
    Log.d("Notifier","started");
    String id[] = intent.getStringArrayExtra("id");
    Log.d("notifier",String.valueOf(id.length));

    if (id!=null) {
        context = contextn;
        backgroundsync back = new backgroundsync();
        back.execute(id);

        Intent callagain = new Intent(context, notifer.class);
        callagain.putExtra("id", id);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, callagain, 0);
        AlarmManager notifalm;
        notifalm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        notifalm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000, alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

Whenever there is a change in data that notifer need to work on I do this from UI thread when the data change is detected.

```
cancelalarm();
//changed data in database here
setalarm();
```

method definition is :

```
private void setalarm()
{
    Intent callagain = new Intent(this,notifer.class);
    String ids[]=interact.checked();
    for (int i=0;i<ids.length;i++)
        Log.d("Main checked new",ids[i]);
    callagain.putExtra("id", ids);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, callagain, 0);
    AlarmManager notifalm;
    notifalm = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    notifalm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),alarmIntent);
}
private void cancelalarm()
{
    Intent callagain = new Intent(this,notifer.class);
    String ids[]=interact.checked();
    for (int i=0;i<ids.length;i++)
        Log.d("Main checked old",ids[i]);
    callagain.putExtra("id", ids);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, callagain, 0);
    AlarmManager notifalm;
    notifalm = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    notifalm.cancel(alarmIntent);
}
```

interact.checked() returns data from database that needs to be sent to notifer.

The problem is even when data is changed the notifer still keeps working on old data. Pls, help I am stuck here for hours.

Let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 0):

It is now working had to replace pendingIntent statement everywhere with this.

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, callagain, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17570455/7732470