# How to delete or cancel all pendingIntent in alarmManager?

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my app, I would like to delete all pendingIntent in my alarmManager.
Is possible to do a `for()` to delete all?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

[Android: Get all PendingIntents set with AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315611/android-get-all-pendingintents-set-with-alarmmanager)

To cancel all alarm, first you have to find all the pending intent for that and cancel alarm using that.

If it is helpful to you than don't miss to accept this as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
// set up alarm 
List<PendingIntent> mPendingIntentList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Receiver.class);
alarmIntent.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + alarm.ID));
alarmIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(alarm.ID));
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0,                  alarmIntent, 0);

// add pending intent in list
mPendingIntentList.add(displayIntent );
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmDateTime, displayIntent);



    //cancel all alarms
    for(int idx = 0 ; idx < mPendingIntentList.size() ; idx++){
       alarmManager .cancel(mPendingIntentList.get(idx));
    }
```

Comment: code commented . Please check now and let me know if there are any issues :)

Answer (score -2):

See [AlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Create a PendingIntent matching the intent(s) you wish to cancel. Calling the above function once, will cancel all matching alarms
.

Comment: How to get each PendingIntent?

Comment: @Roel, you don't need to. You just need 1 pending intent matching your alarm and AlarmManager.clancel() will cancel all the ones that match.