# Cancel All Alarms each with different PendingIntent set using AlarmManager at once without having to recreate each PendingIntent again

Tags: android

I have set multiple repeating alarms each with different PendingIntent.
Is there a way to cancel all these alarms at once?
The only way i find to cancel alarms is to create individual PendingIntent and then call AlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) method. 
As I have many different alarms with different PendingIntent i will have to recreate all those, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no other way to cancel the alarms

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do is recreate your pending intent and cancel it.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyPendingIntentService.class);
PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, updateServiceIntent, 0);
    // Cancel it
    try{
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Update failed " + e.getMessage());
     }
```

[Courtsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315611/android-get-all-pendingintents-set-with-alarmmanager)