# Alarm Manager is repeating more than once a day when using AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY

Tags: java, android

MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver24.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
String time= String.valueOf(calendar.getTime());
Log.i("Time:",time);
//repeat alarm every 24hours
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver24 extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        reference.child("Total").setValue(0);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Total Reset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver24"/>
```

I want the code to run at midnight 12:00:00 once everyday but it keeps firing again and again even after using AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alarm was getting set in past so added this condition and it was solved

```
if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance()))
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you opens `MainActivity` it creates a new `PendingIntent`

When you start `MainActivity` you should [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315611/android-get-all-pendingintents-set-with-alarmmanager/4316252#4316252) all previously scheduled alarms.

Also

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

is not midnight.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

is midnight

Comment: if i cancel the pending intent then it is not calling the alarm at all where do i need to specific the cancel() method

Comment: creating of Alarm each time you opens it is a bed solution. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmanager-already-has-an-alarm-set) one.